# Copy data upto last used Row of a specific column

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I am using this code to get the last used rows-

`rowNo=objExcel.Activeworkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.count`

Now, i want to copy the data of a specific column upto last row used.

//What to write in the below code to use rowNo //

`Set Source=objExcel.Activeworkbook.Sheets(1).Column("G")`

`Source.Copy`

Answer (score 1):

That's the incorrect way to find the last row. See the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) on how to find the last row.

Once you have found the last row then simply use this code to copy

```
ws.Range("G1:G" & rowNo).Copy
```

Where `ws` is the worksheet object.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Just have one query-

When i am pasting all the values in the excel , all values are getting overlapped on one-another.How can i make it to paste one by one...

Set dest=objExcel2.Activeworkbook.Sheets(1).Columns("A")
dest.PasteSpecial

Comment: Sorry I do not understand? Do you want to transpose the data from the column to a row?

Comment: No, There are some excel files in a folder.I am trying to copy a specific column value and put it into a single excel sheet.What you had suggested with the help of that i am able to copy all the values but while pasting it into a new excel sheet.All these values are getting pasted over one-another.I want all these values to be pasted one by one( like if there are 12 values in the first sheet then it will be pasted after this second sheet values and so on..)

Comment: That is because you are pasting it in Col A directly. You have to find the last row in the destination sheet as well and then paste after that